# CakePHP: Check for line item in iframe before submitting parent form

Tags: php, cakephp, iframe

The app I'm working on (an order form) allows the user to enter multiple sub-records within an iframe. These sub-records are joined to the main record via a foreign key.

```
main_records                line_items
-----------                 ----------    
 id int(11) PK etc.          id int(11) PK etc.
                             main_record_id (FK)
```

I need the app to check whether at least one line item exists within this iframe before form submission. I would like to take advantage of the $validate functionality within the model, but I'm unsure how to proceed. Here's what I've tried in the Main model:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model', 'LineItem');

public $hasMany = array(
    'LineItem' => array(
        'className' => 'LineItem',
        'foreignKey' => 'main_record_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);

public $validate = array(
    'main_record_id' = array(
         'allowEmpty' => false,
         'rule' => 'checkForLineItem',
         'message' => 'You must enter at least one line item!'
    )
);

//Check to make sure there is at least one line item before saving changes/submitting for approval
function checkForLineItem($id) {
    $lines = $this->LineItem->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('LineItem.main_record_id'),
        'conditions' => array('LineItem.main_record_id'=>$id, 'LineItem.deleted_record'=>0))
    );
    if(!empty($lines)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also track whether the line item has been deleted. If it has, then it is not added to $lines.

I know I can accomplish this in the Controller, but as far as I know, that would require the form to post, and the user would lose any changes upon postback (I haven't yet implemented jQuery on this form). Am I on the right track with how to do this? What changes should I make to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks about right, but validation indeed happens in form submit. If you want to check it prior to that you have to do in JavaScript (jquery). E.g. create a controller action that return if there are existing line items for given main record id and call it via AJAX.